# How did I end up with 16.04 LTS but 2.6.32 kernel, and how to fix it?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, kernel

For some reason, my VPS seems to be running Ubuntu 16.04.1 with the 2.6.32 kernel.
How could I possibly have ended up here, given that 16.04.1 comes with the 4.4 kernel?
And how can I safely fix this problem?

I tried `apt install linux-generic` (and rebooting afterwards) but this didn't help.

---

#### Diagnostic info

When I log on to my VPS, I get:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-042stab117.14 x86_64)
```

Relevant command output:

```
$ lsb_release -r
Release:    16.04
$ uname -r
2.6.32-042stab117.14
```

Comment: Look into VPS menu or contact your VPS provider.

Comment: That is not the Ubuntu kernel number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`2.6.32-042stab117.14` is the kernel number for [Virtuozzo](https://virtuozzo.com/) ([OpenVZ](https://openvz.org/Main_Page)).

> OpenVZ is a container-based virtualization for Linux. OpenVZ creates multiple secure, isolated Linux containers (otherwise known as VEs or VPSs) on a single physical server enabling better server utilization and ensuring that applications do not conflict. Each container performs and executes exactly like a stand-alone server; a container can be rebooted independently and have root access, users, IP addresses, memory, processes, files, applications, system libraries and configuration files.
>
> OpenVZ is free open source software, available under GNU GPL.

---

And they also include Ubuntu as a container.

The version numbering is explained [here](https://wiki.openvz.org/Kernel_versioning):

> **New-style versioning**
>
> Currently (since 2.6.20) all new OpenVZ kernels has a simple version like 2.6.n-ovzXXX

- 2.6.n is a vanilla kernel version, e.g. 2.6.20 or 2.6.22, which this OpenVZ kernel is based on;
- ovzXXX is the OpenVZ kernel version, e.g. ovz001 for the very first one.

> **Old-style versioning**
>
> Some time ago OpenVZ kernel versions were named like 2.6.n-XXXtestYYY.z and 2.6.n-XXXstabYYY.z.

- 2.6.n is a vanilla kernel version (i.e. the one from kernel.org) which this OpenVZ kernel is based on.
- XXX is a major OpenVZ kernel version number, which usually changes from release to release, or when dramatic changes to the kernel are made.
- test series kernels are unstable kernel releases, which are usually under extensive development, while stab series kernels are more or less stable kernel releases which are close to be released or are in production already.
- YYY is a minor OpenVZ kernel version number, which changes from build to build, when bugfixes or small feature changes were made.
- z is an add-on number; it is used as rpm's Release field and in most cases is set to 1.

> This style is kept for some kernels that started before switching to the new versioning.